# Unable to reconnect 3G connection after new IP was given

Tags: debian, ip, 3g

I use Debian Jessie 8.2 and I am using a 3G connection using [Huawei MU709 Mini PCIe](http://consumer.huawei.com/en/solutions/m2m-solutions/products/tech-specs/mu709s-2-minipcie-en.htm).

The 3G connection works fine, except after 24 hours the connection drops and I cannot reconnect. If I reboot the computer, the connection will work again.

My guess is that my ISP gives me a new IP address after 24 hours and somehow my system cannot handle it.

How can I reconnect my 3G connection without rebooting?

I have already tried the following commands:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

and also:

```
dhclient -r eth0
dhclient eth0
```

**EDIT 1:**

Results of `journalctl` and grepping my connection name (`SFR`)

```
sept. 22 17:58:19 ark1 NetworkManager[512]: <info> Policy set 'SFR Web / Prepaid 1' (eth0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS.
sept. 23 18:17:07 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> new connection /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/SFR Web * Prepaid 1
sept. 23 18:17:08 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> Auto-activating connection 'SFR Web / Prepaid 1'.
sept. 23 18:17:08 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> Activation (ttyUSB0) starting connection 'SFR Web / Prepaid 1'
sept. 23 18:17:53 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <warn> Activation (ttyUSB0) failed for connection 'SFR Web / Prepaid 1'
sept. 23 18:17:53 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> Auto-activating connection 'SFR Web / Prepaid 1'.
sept. 23 18:17:53 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> Activation (ttyUSB0) starting connection 'SFR Web / Prepaid 1'
sept. 23 18:18:03 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <warn> Activation (ttyUSB0) failed for connection 'SFR Web / Prepaid 1'
sept. 23 18:18:03 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> Auto-activating connection 'SFR Web / Prepaid 1'.
sept. 23 18:18:03 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> Activation (ttyUSB0) starting connection 'SFR Web / Prepaid 1'
sept. 23 18:18:13 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <warn> Activation (ttyUSB0) failed for connection 'SFR Web / Prepaid 1'
```

As you can see `sept 22 at time 17:18` is when the computer started up. And roughly 24 hours after it failed to reconnect.

Also I should mention that there is a script to run the command:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

if the computer cannot ping a server, ie if the connection is lost.

**EDIT 2:** 
Added more `journalctl` info when the system tries to reconnect:

```
sept. 23 23:52:53 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> Auto-activating connection 'SFR'.
sept. 23 23:52:53 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> Activation (ttyUSB0) starting connection 'SFR'
sept. 23 23:52:53 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> Activation (ttyUSB0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) scheduled...
sept. 23 23:52:53 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> Activation (ttyUSB0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) started...
sept. 23 23:52:53 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> (ttyUSB0): device state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
sept. 23 23:52:53 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> Activation (ttyUSB0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) complete.
sept. 23 23:52:53 ark1 ModemManager[518]: <info>  Simple connect started...
sept. 23 23:52:53 ark1 ModemManager[518]: <info>  Simple connect state (4/8): Wait to get fully enabled
sept. 23 23:52:53 ark1 ModemManager[518]: <info>  Simple connect state (5/8): Register
sept. 23 23:52:53 ark1 ModemManager[518]: <info>  Simple connect state (6/8): Bearer
sept. 23 23:52:53 ark1 ModemManager[518]: <info>  Simple connect state (7/8): Connect
sept. 23 23:52:53 ark1 ModemManager[518]: <info>  Simple connect state (8/8): All done
sept. 23 23:52:53 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> Activation (ttyUSB0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) scheduled...
sept. 23 23:52:53 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> Activation (ttyUSB0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) starting...
sept. 23 23:52:53 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> (ttyUSB0): device state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
sept. 23 23:52:53 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> Activation (ttyUSB0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful.
sept. 23 23:52:53 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> Activation (ttyUSB0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) scheduled.
sept. 23 23:52:53 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> Activation (ttyUSB0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) complete.
sept. 23 23:52:53 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> Activation (ttyUSB0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) started...
sept. 23 23:52:53 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> (ttyUSB0): device state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none') [50 70 0]
sept. 23 23:52:53 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> Activation (eth0) Beginning DHCPv4 transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
sept. 23 23:52:53 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> dhclient started with pid 13212
sept. 23 23:52:53 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> Activation (ttyUSB0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) scheduled...
sept. 23 23:52:53 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> Activation (ttyUSB0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) complete.
sept. 23 23:52:53 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> Activation (ttyUSB0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) started...
sept. 23 23:52:53 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> Activation (ttyUSB0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) complete.
sept. 23 23:52:53 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> (eth0): DHCPv4 state changed nbi -> preinit
sept. 23 23:52:53 ark1 dhclient[13212]: DHCPREQUEST on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
sept. 23 23:52:59 ark1 dhclient[13212]: DHCPREQUEST on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
sept. 23 23:53:09 ark1 dhclient[13212]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 5
sept. 23 23:53:14 ark1 dhclient[13212]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8
sept. 23 23:53:22 ark1 dhclient[13212]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 10
sept. 23 23:53:32 ark1 dhclient[13212]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 11
sept. 23 23:53:38 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <warn> (eth0): DHCPv4 request timed out.
sept. 23 23:53:38 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> (eth0): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 13212
sept. 23 23:53:38 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> Activation (ttyUSB0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv4 Configure Timeout) scheduled...
sept. 23 23:53:38 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> Activation (ttyUSB0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv4 Configure Timeout) started...
sept. 23 23:53:38 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> (ttyUSB0): device state change: ip-config -> failed (reason 'ip-config-unavailable') [70 120 5]
sept. 23 23:53:38 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <warn> Activation (ttyUSB0) failed for connection 'SFR'
sept. 23 23:53:38 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> Activation (ttyUSB0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv4 Configure Timeout) complete.
sept. 23 23:53:38 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> (ttyUSB0): device state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none') [120 30 0]
sept. 23 23:53:38 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> (ttyUSB0): deactivating device (reason 'none') [0]
sept. 23 23:53:38 ark1 avahi-daemon[528]: Withdrawing address record for 169.254.1.156 on eth0.
sept. 23 23:53:38 ark1 avahi-daemon[528]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv4 with address 169.254.1.156.
sept. 23 23:53:38 ark1 avahi-daemon[528]: Interface eth0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
sept. 23 23:53:38 ark1 dhclient[11114]: receive_packet failed on eth0: Network is down
sept. 23 23:53:38 ark1 ModemManager[518]: <info>  Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0: state changed (connected -> disconnecting)
sept. 23 23:53:38 ark1 ModemManager[518]: <warn>  Couldn't find associated cdc-wdm port for 'net/eth0'
sept. 23 23:53:38 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> Auto-activating connection 'SFR'.
sept. 23 23:53:38 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> Activation (ttyUSB0) starting connection 'SFR'
sept. 23 23:53:38 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> Activation (ttyUSB0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) scheduled...
sept. 23 23:53:38 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> Activation (ttyUSB0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) started...
sept. 23 23:53:38 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> (ttyUSB0): device state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
sept. 23 23:53:38 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> Activation (ttyUSB0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) complete.
sept. 23 23:53:38 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> (ttyUSB0): modem state changed, 'connected' --> 'disconnecting' (reason: user-requested)
sept. 23 23:53:38 ark1 avahi-autoipd(eth0)[13202]: SIOCSIFFLAGS failed: Operation not permitted
sept. 23 23:53:38 ark1 avahi-autoipd(eth0)[13202]: Callout STOP, address 169.254.1.156 on interface eth0
sept. 23 23:53:39 ark1 ModemManager[518]: <info>  Simple connect started...
sept. 23 23:53:39 ark1 ModemManager[518]: <info>  Simple connect state (4/8): Wait to get fully enabled
sept. 23 23:53:39 ark1 avahi-autoipd(eth0)[13203]: client: RTNETLINK answers: No such process
sept. 23 23:53:39 ark1 avahi-autoipd(eth0)[13203]: client: RTNETLINK answers: Cannot assign requested address
sept. 23 23:53:39 ark1 avahi-autoipd(eth0)[13203]: Script execution failed with return value 2
sept. 23 23:53:48 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <warn> (ttyUSB0) failed to connect modem: Too much time waiting to get to a final state
sept. 23 23:53:48 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> (ttyUSB0): device state change: prepare -> failed (reason '(null)') [40 120 1]
sept. 23 23:53:48 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <warn> Activation (ttyUSB0) failed for connection 'SFR'
sept. 23 23:53:48 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> (ttyUSB0): device state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none') [120 30 0]
sept. 23 23:53:48 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> (ttyUSB0): deactivating device (reason 'none') [0]
sept. 23 23:53:48 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> Auto-activating connection 'SFR'.
sept. 23 23:53:48 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> Activation (ttyUSB0) starting connection 'SFR'
sept. 23 23:53:48 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> Activation (ttyUSB0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) scheduled...
sept. 23 23:53:48 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> Activation (ttyUSB0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) started...
sept. 23 23:53:48 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> (ttyUSB0): device state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
sept. 23 23:53:48 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> Activation (ttyUSB0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) complete.
sept. 23 23:53:48 ark1 ModemManager[518]: <info>  Simple connect started...
sept. 23 23:53:48 ark1 ModemManager[518]: <info>  Simple connect state (4/8): Wait to get fully enabled
sept. 23 23:53:58 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <warn> (ttyUSB0) failed to connect modem: Too much time waiting to get to a final state
sept. 23 23:53:58 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> (ttyUSB0): device state change: prepare -> failed (reason '(null)') [40 120 1]
sept. 23 23:53:58 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <warn> Activation (ttyUSB0) failed for connection 'SFR'
sept. 23 23:53:58 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> (ttyUSB0): device state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none') [120 30 0]
sept. 23 23:53:58 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> (ttyUSB0): deactivating device (reason 'none') [0]
sept. 23 23:53:58 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> Auto-activating connection 'SFR'.
sept. 23 23:53:58 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> Activation (ttyUSB0) starting connection 'SFR'
sept. 23 23:53:58 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> Activation (ttyUSB0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) scheduled...
sept. 23 23:53:58 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> Activation (ttyUSB0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) started...
sept. 23 23:53:58 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> (ttyUSB0): device state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
sept. 23 23:53:58 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> Activation (ttyUSB0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) complete.
sept. 23 23:53:58 ark1 ModemManager[518]: <info>  Simple connect started...
sept. 23 23:53:58 ark1 ModemManager[518]: <info>  Simple connect state (4/8): Wait to get fully enabled
sept. 23 23:54:08 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <warn> (ttyUSB0) failed to connect modem: Too much time waiting to get to a final state
sept. 23 23:54:08 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> (ttyUSB0): device state change: prepare -> failed (reason '(null)') [40 120 1]
sept. 23 23:54:08 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> Disabling autoconnect for connection 'SFR'.
sept. 23 23:54:08 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <warn> Activation (ttyUSB0) failed for connection 'SFR'
sept. 23 23:54:08 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> (ttyUSB0): device state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none') [120 30 0]
sept. 23 23:54:08 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> (ttyUSB0): deactivating device (reason 'none') [0]
sept. 23 23:54:39 ark1 ModemManager[518]: <info>  Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0: state changed (disconnecting -> connected)
sept. 23 23:54:39 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> (ttyUSB0): modem state changed, 'disconnecting' --> 'connected' (reason: user-requested)
sept. 23 23:55:31 ark1 noip2[1786]: Can't get our visible IP address from ip1.dynupdate.no-ip.com
sept. 23 23:55:50 ark1 dhclient[11114]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 4
sept. 23 23:55:50 ark1 dhclient[11114]: send_packet: Network is down
sept. 23 23:55:50 ark1 dhclient[11114]: dhclient.c:1966: Failed to send 300 byte long packet over eth0 interface.
sept. 23 23:55:54 ark1 dhclient[11114]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8
sept. 23 23:55:54 ark1 dhclient[11114]: send_packet: Network is down
sept. 23 23:55:54 ark1 dhclient[11114]: dhclient.c:1966: Failed to send 300 byte long packet over eth0 interface.
sept. 23 23:56:02 ark1 dhclient[11114]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 11
sept. 23 23:56:02 ark1 dhclient[11114]: send_packet: Network is down
sept. 23 23:56:02 ark1 dhclient[11114]: dhclient.c:1966: Failed to send 300 byte long packet over eth0 interface.
sept. 23 23:56:13 ark1 dhclient[11114]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 10
sept. 23 23:56:13 ark1 dhclient[11114]: send_packet: Network is down
sept. 23 23:56:13 ark1 dhclient[11114]: dhclient.c:1966: Failed to send 300 byte long packet over eth0 interface.
sept. 23 23:56:23 ark1 dhclient[11114]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 11
sept. 23 23:56:23 ark1 dhclient[11114]: send_packet: Network is down
sept. 23 23:56:23 ark1 dhclient[11114]: dhclient.c:1966: Failed to send 300 byte long packet over eth0 interface.
sept. 23 23:56:34 ark1 dhclient[11114]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 9
sept. 23 23:56:34 ark1 dhclient[11114]: send_packet: Network is down
sept. 23 23:56:34 ark1 dhclient[11114]: dhclient.c:1966: Failed to send 300 byte long packet over eth0 interface.
sept. 23 23:56:43 ark1 dhclient[11114]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8
sept. 23 23:56:43 ark1 dhclient[11114]: send_packet: Network is down
sept. 23 23:56:43 ark1 dhclient[11114]: dhclient.c:1966: Failed to send 300 byte long packet over eth0 interface.
sept. 23 23:56:51 ark1 dhclient[11114]: No DHCPOFFERS received.
sept. 23 23:56:51 ark1 dhclient[11114]: No working leases in persistent database - sleeping.
sept. 23 23:56:51 ark1 avahi-autoipd(eth0)[13229]: Found user 'avahi-autoipd' (UID 109) and group 'avahi-autoipd' (GID 118).
sept. 23 23:56:51 ark1 avahi-autoipd(eth0)[13229]: Successfully called chroot().
sept. 23 23:56:51 ark1 avahi-autoipd(eth0)[13229]: Successfully dropped root privileges.
sept. 23 23:56:51 ark1 avahi-autoipd(eth0)[13229]: Starting with address 169.254.1.156
sept. 23 23:56:57 ark1 avahi-autoipd(eth0)[13229]: Callout BIND, address 169.254.1.156 on interface eth0
sept. 23 23:56:57 ark1 avahi-daemon[528]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv4 with address 169.254.1.156.
sept. 23 23:56:57 ark1 avahi-daemon[528]: New relevant interface eth0.IPv4 for mDNS.
sept. 23 23:56:57 ark1 avahi-daemon[528]: Registering new address record for 169.254.1.156 on eth0.IPv4.
sept. 23 23:57:01 ark1 avahi-autoipd(eth0)[13229]: Successfully claimed IP address 169.254.1.156
sept. 23 23:59:08 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> Auto-activating connection 'SFR'.
sept. 23 23:59:08 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> Activation (ttyUSB0) starting connection 'SFR'
sept. 23 23:59:08 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> Activation (ttyUSB0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) scheduled...
sept. 23 23:59:08 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> Activation (ttyUSB0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) started...
sept. 23 23:59:08 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> (ttyUSB0): device state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
sept. 23 23:59:08 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> Activation (ttyUSB0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) complete.
sept. 23 23:59:08 ark1 ModemManager[518]: <info>  Simple connect started...
sept. 23 23:59:08 ark1 ModemManager[518]: <info>  Simple connect state (4/8): Wait to get fully enabled
sept. 23 23:59:08 ark1 ModemManager[518]: <info>  Simple connect state (5/8): Register
sept. 23 23:59:08 ark1 ModemManager[518]: <info>  Simple connect state (6/8): Bearer
sept. 23 23:59:08 ark1 ModemManager[518]: <info>  Simple connect state (7/8): Connect
sept. 23 23:59:08 ark1 ModemManager[518]: <info>  Simple connect state (8/8): All done
sept. 23 23:59:08 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> Activation (ttyUSB0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) scheduled...
sept. 23 23:59:08 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> Activation (ttyUSB0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) starting...
sept. 23 23:59:08 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> (ttyUSB0): device state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
sept. 23 23:59:08 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> Activation (ttyUSB0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful.
sept. 23 23:59:08 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> Activation (ttyUSB0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) scheduled.
sept. 23 23:59:08 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> Activation (ttyUSB0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) complete.
sept. 23 23:59:08 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> Activation (ttyUSB0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) started...
sept. 23 23:59:08 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> (ttyUSB0): device state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none') [50 70 0]
sept. 23 23:59:08 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> Activation (eth0) Beginning DHCPv4 transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
sept. 23 23:59:08 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> dhclient started with pid 13236
sept. 23 23:59:08 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> Activation (ttyUSB0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) scheduled...
sept. 23 23:59:08 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> Activation (ttyUSB0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) complete.
sept. 23 23:59:08 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> Activation (ttyUSB0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) started...
sept. 23 23:59:08 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> Activation (ttyUSB0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) complete.
sept. 23 23:59:08 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> (eth0): DHCPv4 state changed nbi -> preinit
sept. 23 23:59:09 ark1 dhclient[13236]: DHCPREQUEST on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
sept. 23 23:59:17 ark1 dhclient[13236]: DHCPREQUEST on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
sept. 23 23:59:31 ark1 dhclient[13236]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3
sept. 23 23:59:34 ark1 dhclient[13236]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 4
sept. 23 23:59:38 ark1 dhclient[13236]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 11
sept. 23 23:59:49 ark1 dhclient[13236]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 9
sept. 23 23:59:53 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <warn> (eth0): DHCPv4 request timed out.
sept. 23 23:59:53 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> (eth0): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 13236
sept. 23 23:59:53 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> Activation (ttyUSB0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv4 Configure Timeout) scheduled...
sept. 23 23:59:53 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> Activation (ttyUSB0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv4 Configure Timeout) started...
sept. 23 23:59:53 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> (ttyUSB0): device state change: ip-config -> failed (reason 'ip-config-unavailable') [70 120 5]
sept. 23 23:59:53 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <warn> Activation (ttyUSB0) failed for connection 'SFR'
sept. 23 23:59:53 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> Activation (ttyUSB0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv4 Configure Timeout) complete.
sept. 23 23:59:53 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> (ttyUSB0): device state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none') [120 30 0]
sept. 23 23:59:53 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> (ttyUSB0): deactivating device (reason 'none') [0]
sept. 23 23:59:53 ark1 avahi-daemon[528]: Withdrawing address record for 169.254.1.156 on eth0.
sept. 23 23:59:53 ark1 avahi-daemon[528]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv4 with address 169.254.1.156.
sept. 23 23:59:53 ark1 avahi-daemon[528]: Interface eth0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
sept. 23 23:59:53 ark1 dhclient[11114]: receive_packet failed on eth0: Network is down
sept. 23 23:59:53 ark1 avahi-autoipd(eth0)[13229]: SIOCSIFFLAGS failed: Operation not permitted
sept. 23 23:59:53 ark1 avahi-autoipd(eth0)[13229]: Callout STOP, address 169.254.1.156 on interface eth0
sept. 23 23:59:53 ark1 ModemManager[518]: <info>  Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0: state changed (connected -> disconnecting)
sept. 23 23:59:53 ark1 ModemManager[518]: <warn>  Couldn't find associated cdc-wdm port for 'net/eth0'
sept. 23 23:59:53 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> (ttyUSB0): modem state changed, 'connected' --> 'disconnecting' (reason: user-requested)
sept. 23 23:59:53 ark1 NetworkManager[9446]: <info> Auto-activating connection 'SFR'.
```

I also tried the answer of Wouter Verhelst but it did not work:

```
systemctl restart ModemManager
```

**EDIT 3:**

`NetworkManager.conf` file:

```
[main] plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown] managed=false
```

**EDIT 4:**

```
$ ip link show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0b:ab:9d:7c:20 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: eth2: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0b:ab:9c:29:84 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: eth3: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0b:ab:9c:29:85 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:1e:10:1f:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

**EDIT 5:**

When the connection is working:

```
ps ax | grep 'pppd' | grep -v 'grep'
```

does not output anything.

**EDIT 6:**

```
~$ mmcli -m 0

/org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0 (device id 'cd32f4358dd82cdb976fcc9df44df11737726856')
  -------------------------
  Hardware |   manufacturer: 'Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd.'
           |          model: 'MU709s-2'
           |       revision: '11.651.67.00.00'
           |      supported: 'gsm-umts'
           |        current: 'gsm-umts'
           |   equipment id: '864881021266208'
  -------------------------
  System   |         device: '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb5/5-6'
           |        drivers: 'option1, cdc_ether'
           |         plugin: 'Huawei'
           |   primary port: 'ttyUSB0'
           |          ports: 'ttyUSB0 (at), ttyUSB2 (at), ttyUSB3 (at), eth0 (net)'
  -------------------------
  Numbers  |           own : 'unknown'
  -------------------------
  Status   |           lock: 'none'
           | unlock retries: 'sim-pin (3), sim-pin2 (3), sim-puk (10), sim-puk2 (10)'
           |          state: 'connected'
           |    power state: 'on'
           |    access tech: 'umts'
           | signal quality: '32' (recent)
  -------------------------
  Modes    |      supported: 'allowed: 2g, 3g; preferred: none
           |                  allowed: 2g, 3g; preferred: 2g
           |                  allowed: 2g, 3g; preferred: 3g
           |                  allowed: 2g; preferred: none
           |                  allowed: 3g; preferred: none'
           |        current: 'allowed: 2g, 3g; preferred: 3g'
  -------------------------
  Bands    |      supported: 'unknown'
           |        current: 'unknown'
  -------------------------
  IP       |      supported: 'ipv4'
  -------------------------
  3GPP     |           imei: '864881021266208'
           |  enabled locks: 'none'
           |    operator id: '20810'
           |  operator name: 'F SFR'
           |   subscription: 'unknown'
           |   registration: 'home'
  -------------------------
  SIM      |           path: '/org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/SIM/0'

  -------------------------
  Bearers  |          paths: '/org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Bearer/0'
```

**LAST EDIT:**

Only solution I found was to change the MU709 modem for the VIA EMIO-2550. I don't have connection issues with the VIA one.

Comment: There should be logs (e.g., check `journalctl`).. is there anything around the time it stops working?

Comment: added journalctl logs

Comment: Opps, your system configured the network interfaces in somewhat different way, every network interface (except loopback) is showing as a `eth*` device, and how it could connect to a mobile wwan network without a pppd dial ? Really strange. Could you connect to the `/dev/ttyUSB0` interface with a serial connection app. like Putty ? Strange !

Comment: @Arnab Strange yeah, the computer model is an Advantech ARK-2120 if that can help. And yes I can connect to `/dev/ttyUSB0` with Putty or `busybox microcom`.

Comment: Hi Romain, your industrial PC is cool, with two GbE ethernet NIC. Did you tried with `AT+CFUN=0` and `AT+CFUN=1` AT commands after connecting to the modem control port `/dev/ttyUSB0` ? I'hv only USB modems, they connects through pppd, where most problems could be solved by AT commands. The same thing applies on old nokia phones. In your case, NetworkManager is treating the GSM card as an ethernet device.  Try to find out the documention of your GSM card, certainly there will be some thing to reset your modem. As mentioned bellow, do some test with ModemManager too, `mmcli -m 0`  .

Comment: @Arnab yes I tried the AT commands you mentionned but it did not work. I use this [modem](http://consumer.huawei.com/en/solutions/m2m-solutions/products/tech-specs/mu709s-2-minipcie-en.htm). I will look though the AT commands.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure about your GSM connection uses `eth0` interface ? In most cases it is `ppp0`, `wwan0` or `usb0` with latest MBIM protocol. `eth0` interface with mobile broadband is quite uncommon.

It seems that your GMS card uses the `/dev/ttyUSB0` interface for connecting to the actual mobile broadband network via `pppd` and transfers that connection to a private DHCP network via the `eth0` interface.
169.254.x.x IP range is link local address, used to provide simple DHCP connection.

So mobile broadband will not be available if NetworkManager fails to dial the pppd connection.

My experiance, ISPs never change the IP address if you are connected, and they always provide different IP address after each reconnect, at least with mobile broadband.

Now what happens, (again, my personal experience) the modem **hangs up** , as this is a mini PCIe card, you can't simply plug out and plug in it. Here the old fashioned **AT** commands are useful.

Try to connect the `/dev/ttyUSB0` port with your favorite serial connection app, like `Putty`, `minicom`, `cutecom`, `cu`, `busybox microcom` etc. etc. I'm using the crude `busybox microcom`.

```
nmcli radio wwan off
sudo busybox microcom -t 10000 /dev/ttyUSB0
```

Put these AT commands there.

```
ATZ
AT+CFUN=0
```

Wait for 10sec. and connect it again.

```
sudo busybox microcom -t 10000 /dev/ttyUSB0
AT+CFUN=1
```

Now exit and try to connect through NetworkManager applet again.

When the mobile broadband connection is active, run the command bellow and please update your question.

```
ps ax | grep 'pppd' | grep -v 'grep'
```

Your GSM card is great, lots of advanced features, unfortunately not working properly.

Comment: I was able to run the AT commands with `busybox microcom` but it did not work

Comment: `ps ax | grep 'pppd' | grep -v 'grep'` doest not output anything

Answer (score 2):

NetworkManager is involved in dealing with the 3G modem, but only in a small way. The actual program that talks to your modem is called ModemManager. I've noticed on my laptop that it sometimes loses the connection too, and then

```
systemctl restart ModemManager
```

is sufficient.

Comment: I tried but it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

The log output from `journalctl` isn't clear on what is causing this to happen. I would recommend doing the following in order:

1). Try manually setting the interface up when this happens:

```
ifconfig eth0 up
```

Alternatively, if you don't have `ifconfig` installed, you can do this with `ip`:

```
ip link set dev eth0 up
```

2). If that doesn't help, check `/var/log/syslog` for related messages.

If I had to make an educated guess, this is a configuration issue associated with the modem itself. Can you post the NetworkManager configuration file itself, stripping any sensitive information that may be in it?

Comment: `ip link set dev eth0 up` does not work. I have edited my question to add the NeworkManager configuration file. I will post the /var/log/syslog a bit later.

Comment: The ip device name may be different than what NetworkManager uses. Use the command `ip link show` to list the available interfaces. If /var/log/syslog, it may be named differently (I don't recall what Debian calls it). Check /var/log/messages or maybe /var/log/messages/log.

Comment: I added the `ip link show` output. I also looked at /var/log/syslog but it looks like it is the same as looking at `journalctl` ?